# DTLS-CoAP server from Contiki-NG fails during DTLS handshake

Tags: coap, dtls, contiki-ng, californium

I have flashed a cc2650 Sensortag with cc26xx-web-demo example in Contiki-NG with option MAKE_WITH_DTLS=1 now I want to access it through a coaps:// request. When I try to access it as coaps:// from cf-browser it shows handshake failed but it works fine with simple coap:// request. The demo server (californium.eclipseprojects.io) provided in cf-browser works on both coap and coaps. I have also tried accessing it with libcoap client but no luck.

Any idea what could be wrong with my implementation? There are any proper guides tutorials for DTLS-CoAP sever implementation in Contiki-NG?

Answer (score 0):

DTLS as used in CoAP (and especially with the key stores [available in contiki](https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/blob/df0a157b2335ff9c3bfd40052edf66b8a1cb2c2b/os/net/app-layer/coap/Makefile.coap) (which default to LwM2M) needs preshared keys between the client and the server; attempts to connect will fail without matching keys.

Unless you plan to use this with LwM2M (which the question gave no indication to), you can pick the simple key store by defining [MAKE_COAP_DTLS_KEYSTORE_SIMPLE](https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/blob/df0a157b2335ff9c3bfd40052edf66b8a1cb2c2b/os/net/app-layer/coap/Makefile.coap), and setting [user and key](https://contiki-ng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/group__coap-keystore.html) because you may not want to use the default ones.

Then, you can pass [`--identity` and `--secret` to cf-browser](https://github.com/eclipse/californium.tools/blob/master/cf-browser/README.md).

Comment: Hey, I set `MAKE_COAP_DTLS_KEYSTORE=MAKE_COAP_DTLS_KEYSTORE_SIMPLE` while building already and also added                                                                                    
`#define COAP_DTLS_PSK_DEFAULT_IDENTITY "Client_identity"`
`#define COAP_DTLS_PSK_DEFAULT_KEY      "secretPSK"` in the project-conf.h and passed both the identity and key in the credentials section in the cf-browser

Comment: Then by all means please put that information into the question, and give a more verbose description of the error case, and any log output you see on either side.

Comment: I've checked it with a libcoap client as well. It seems that the issue is with the sensortag firmware not cf-broswer.

Comment: The problem I am facing has already been listed in [issue #863](https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/issues/863) on the contiki-NG github repository but no one has so far solved it.

Comment: As chrysn already wrote, with the information you provide, it's hard to help you. Maybe you can reproduce it with a local installed plugtest-server and use https://github.com/eclipse/californium/wiki/Logs-and-IP-Capturing-%E2%80%90-How-To-Provide-The-Right-Information to provide ip-captures? The issue you found in contiki could at least execute one successful handshake. So I would expect at least that.

Comment: Let me add: tinyDTLS is generally able to execute DTLS handshakes with Californium. If the second doesn't work, that maybe also an issue of the server (hope it's not Californium).

Comment: Yes, I figured its not californium. The problem is with Contiki-NG and in my case it does not execute a single handshake. 
I have posted the output [here](http://paste.pics/E1XRD)

Comment: The difference between a picture and the capture is, that I can't explore the picture. My link above to do caputures will help, if you want help. Just in the case, you may also create an issue in https://github.com/eclipse/californium/issues and upload the capture there (please only the messages after filtering, as descriped in the refered wiki!)

Comment: I asked the contiki-ng community begin of the year to update tinydtls, though that made large progress last year and this year. Unfortunately, either the interest or the possibilities seems to be too low. Still, if you want, you may try to update tinydtls on your own, https://github.com/contiki-ng/tinydtls/issues/29